# Can someone explain the ending of "Enemy"?

Tags: enemy

I thought the movie [*Enemy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2316411/) was about a man and his doppelganger but the end got me confused on so many levels...

I had to watch the movie a few times again, collecting clues and looking for explanations but I could not sum them up conclusively.

Can someone connect the dots?

Answer (score 3):

Forrest Wickman offers [the following theory](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2014/03/14/enemy_movie_ending_explained_the_meaning_of_the_jake_gyllenhaal_and_denis.html) over at Slate:

> I’ll offer a theory. While Enemy has been billed as an erotic thriller
>   and a doppelganger movie—and it is both those things—I think
>   ultimately it’s a parable about what it’s like to live under a
>   totalitarian state without knowing it. It’s an Invasion of the Body
>   Snatchers movie in which you don’t even realize it’s an Invasion of
>   the Body Snatchers movie until the end—until it’s too late for our
>   hero. In this case, the body snatchers just happen to be giant
>   spiders.

I won't quote the whole article, follow the link and read it there.

Note that [the movie's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_(2013_film)) also contains some analysis:

> [A review in Indiewire](http://blogs.indiewire.com/theplaylist/review-denis-villeneuves-terrifically-haunting-enemy-starring-jake-gyllenhaal-20140313) compared the film to Christopher Nolan's
>   Memento, and called it an "engrossing Kafka-eque[sic] mindfuck cum
>   provocative psychological thriller" that "doesn't reveal itself
>   easily". Both director Villeneuve and leading actor Gyllenhaal
>   spoke of their desire to make the film a challenging exploration of
>   the subconscious. To Villeneuve, Enemy is ultimately about
>   repetition: the question of how to live and learn without repeating
>   the same mistakes.
>
> Regarding the two physically identical characters: "You don't know if
>   they are two in reality, or maybe from a subconscious point of view,
>   there's just one," [said Villeneuve](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/enemy-director-jake-gyllenhaals-identical-688439). "It's maybe two sides of the same
>   persona … or a fantastic event where you see another [self]."
>   Gyllenhaal says that Enemy is "about a man who is married, his wife is
>   pregnant, and he’s having an affair. He has to figure himself out
>   before he can commit to life as an adult."

Comment: I'm rather amused that many people see the spiders as literal entities within the film.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to recognise here is that (like other [non-linear](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)/[surrealist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2084989/) films of its type) you're **not supposed to wholly understand what's going on, but simply to enjoy the ride.**

### So what do we know?

Well, for starters there's only one main character, not two. The director as much as confirmed this in an interview shortly after the film was released. The whole "*I've seen a doppelganger who's an actor*" schtick appears to be the main character (Jake) coming to terms with his failed acting career, which he ended the day his partner told him she was pregnant. This explains why his "double" hasn't visited the acting agency since then.

> *When somebody asked me recently to explain the movie I said: “You know
>   what, **this movie is a very simple story, it’s a man who decides to
>   leave his mistress and go back to his wife,** and **we see this story from
>   his subconscious point of view.”** This is the way I read the book, and
>   this is what I tried to do in making the movie. It’s the simplest
>   story but told in a very complex way.* - [Filmcomment.com interview](http://www.filmcomment.com/blog/interview-denis-villeneuve/)

### So what's with all the spiders?

The spiders represent women, as viewed from Jake's own perspective. They appear to turn into spiders *when his split personality begins to manifest itself*, but then turn back into women when he's stabilised again. A giant spider appears on the horizon shortly before his meeting with his mother, he sees a spider with a woman's body, he sees Helen as a spider at the end of the film shying away from him. The city also stars as its own (female) character, one that the director recognises as being in real trouble, caught in the grip of totalitarianism

> *The city in the book and the movie is an very important character. In
>   the book it was described as a megalopolis, a never ending city, with
>   millions of souls. I was looking for a specific landscape, an urban
>   landscape that feels like it is spreading forever. There are not a lot
>   of cities in the world that can offer that. I was looking for one that
>   is in English, an Anglophone city because I wanted the movie to be in
>   English and I wanted it to be set in a poetic landscape, but a
>   realistic landscape, at the same time.* -[Indiewire Interview](http://blogs.indiewire.com/theplaylist/interview-denis-villeneuve-talks-shooting-toronto-for-enemy-dipping-into-the-subconscious-his-next-projects-20140317)

The spiders also represent the [director's shorthand](http://bbook.com/film/dissecting-enemy-director-denis-villeneuve/) for "*you (the audience) should feel uncomfortable*"

> *The spider is a very precise image. The Double is a very complex, yet
>   very simple story that is expressed in a very complicated way. There
>   were some elements in the book that took 45 pages to express, and I
>   said to myself, I cannot have the luxury to take 45 minutes to express
>   such an idea, I need one image, a strong image. I always love when
>   filmmakers are trying to express ideas with images that are beyond
>   words, and the spider was a perfect image I found.*
>
> *What I love about this image is that I think **it’s a very strong and
>   poetic image, but I liked the fact that you can understand it with
>   your own sensibility. You can understand it, but it’s an understanding
>   from inside yourself, not from an intellectual point of view, but more
>   from what you feel as you see the image.***

### So why is spider/Helen climbing up the wall at the end?

Although we [the audience] didn't hear what made Helen scared, she's clearly heard *something*, some verbal shorthand that she recognises as being a trigger for violence. He's in the process of transitioning to his alter personality (which is why he sees her as a spider) and there's a real possibility that he's going to assault or kill her in order to perpetuate this dream world that he's created.